# How to store ajax response in class and get data again when we click on that element

Tags: jquery, html

I got somevalyes in `data` via ajax

i am storeing data in class `class="' + data + '"`

```
  $.each(response.d, function (i, data) {
                    var id = data.Soid;
                    var title = data.Name;
                    debugger;
                    $("#ulAchievementCarousel").append('<li id="' + id + '" title="' + title + '"><img src="../Images/DefaultImage.png" class="' + data + '" /><img src="../Images/trashIcon.png" class="trash" /></li>');
                });
```

Now i want to get those data when i click on image :-

```
$("#ulAchievementCarousel img[src='../Images/DefaultImage.png']").live("click", function () {
        var str = $(this).attr('class');
```

and agian get value from that class and want to display something like this

```
var id = str.Soid;
var title = str.Name;
```

but problem is when i get str from class , value is  `:[object Object]`

Comment: Use `.data()` to store data in a DOM element, not class. That's not what class is intended for! Also, use `.on()` rather than `.live()` to bind events.

Comment: ok, you can suggest me any alternative for not storing class, thanks

Comment: I just did. Use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: ok,can you answer this post

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) as a place to store arbitrary data in a DOM element:

```
var data = { foo: "bar" };
$("#myElement").data("stuff",data);
```

And you can retrieve it later like this:

```
var data = $("#myElement").data("stuff");
console.log(data.foo);      // writes "bar" in the console.
```

Here's a very simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULfcR/) to demonstrate.

Comment: ok, matt, but problem is why i got value like :[object Object], when i am retrive the data

Comment: @NestorC: Right, because it's an object. If you `alert(someObject)`, most browsers will display `[object Object]` because that's what the default `.toString` method does. Try accessing it's properties, as I do in my example.